# How to write a test that checks TLB locking and invalidation?

Tags: tlb, mmu

I am trying to validate a software MMU.

In the testcase which I got, I need to check "TLB locking and invalidation".

I ran a test and checked for the TLB miss, but I was not able to understand what exactly TLB locking and invalidation mean.

Answer (score 1):

TLB stand for Translation Lookaside Buffer. When the MMU is activated and one accesses virtual memory. The MMU needs to translation the virtual address to a physical address. The MMU does this by making reads (typically 2 reads) to RAM which stores the mapping between the virtual address and the corresponding physical address. Since accessing RAM is slow, the mapping is cached in the TLB. This means that subsequent MMU lookups can just check the TLB and do not have to access RAM.

When one switches processes, one reprograms the MMU with the new processes page tables. At this point one needs to invalidate the TLB to ensure that we do not access the memory allocated to the old process.

ARM include a series of performance registers and one of them will increment whenever a TLB miss is experienced. You can possibly use this in your test.

The best place to look for more info is probably the [ARM Architectural Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html) although it is not light reading.